# Datagridview keep cell formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` with a couple of cells that have a red border. At some point I will need to insert new rows into the existing grid but maintain the red border and add, if needed, the red border to some of the new rows too. Can this be done without having to re-color the whole grid after inserting the new rows? If so, how?

**Edit:**

When the user clicks a button new rows will be added, and the first and second will have to be colored in red. I do this by using DrawRectangle on the button's click event. See image below.

[image]

But if the user clicks on another button some other rows will be added, and also marked in red. I am using the same method as for the previous ones, but the initial rows are not marked anymore (see image below).

[image]

Comment: How do you create the red borders?

Comment: I am using DrawRectangle.

Comment: In the CellPainting event? since yo most likely use some numbers to decide which cell to adorn yo will have to adapt these numbers. Or, if you store references to certain cells, these will stay intact and move with the inserted rows..

Comment: No, on button click, after the new rows are added, I use DrawRectangle. I added some screen shots of how it looks.

Comment: Huh? I hope I misread that: You __must not__ draw in a button click! If you do the result will not persist, i.e. will disappear upon e.g. Minimize/Maximize. You can __only__ draw in the `CellPainting` event!!

Comment: I'm new to gridview painting. And didn't know what is the best way. Thank you.

Comment: No rpoblem. There a one or two gazillion posts on correct drawing in Winform here one SO. So, just to re-iterate those posts: Please note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.  The system needs to draw all the controls' surfaces at times you can't control; therefore all you want to add to those surfaces must be created from the one event that the system will call, which is the `Paint` event. (or in your case the Cell_Painiting event)

Comment: Only __non-persistent__ graphics operation like displaying a dynamic rubber-band rectangle are ok with a `Graphics` object you get from `control.CreateGraphics()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CellPainting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event to conditionally draw the border

Move your logic that determines whether the red border appears so that it can be associated with cell data. At a crude level this could be done by simply storing data into the cell [tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) to indicate it should be red bordered